# Web push permission request from native app

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, web-push

Is it possible to somehow request web push permission from within a native Android app. Opening a browser windows within the app or some other way.

The idea is to retain the ability send push (web) to users, even id they decide to uninstall native apps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to somehow request web push permission from within a native Android app.

Currently the Android  WebView doesn't support web push.

> Opening a browser windows within the app or some other way.

If you can open a browser window than yes: you can use web push from the browser window... I don't know if this is a good user experience.